# What is the code of the sorted function?

Tags: python, function, sorting

I was thinking about pre-made functions, and I was asking myself how some functions are written. So is there any database where I can find how functions were written?

My aim is to know how functions were built to get a better understanding of them. The function that I want to know how is it written is the `sorted` function, but in case I need to know others, a way to get the functions' script is highly necessary.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort

Comment: For CPython, you'll find a lot of the code for sorting lists [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d8f48717b74e/Objects/listobject.c#l958). It's quite an involved piece of work. You can also find supporting notes describing the algorithm and its implementation [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d8f48717b74e/Objects/listsort.txt).

Comment: Here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c#L1904

Comment: Thank you guys for all the answers, it helped.